# How to add a subview in settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I want to show my copyright statement as a subview in one of the settings.bundle items. I've googled for this but no much help was found. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: cant you just add it directly to your views???  The question is a little confusing

Answer (score 2):

The look and feel of your settings pane is completely based on the XML plist files in your settings bundle. The Settings application reads the plist file and creates views and subviews to match the properties it finds. This may seem limiting, but it's a deliberate move: it makes all the settings panes consistent so the Settings app has a unified feel.

You can create sub-plists in your settings bundle that define "subviews" and allow you to create hierarchical preference interfaces. You can find information about that in the docs here: [Hierarchical Preferences - iPhone Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH13-SW4).

To display your copyright statement, you could have one of these sub-plists define only a "PSTextFieldSpecifier" field. Then the user could click the "Copyright" item in your prefs, and see the entire interface slide to the left to reveal your copyright text.

Hope that helps!

- Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can make this possible with [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)

In Settings.bundle you need Root.inApp.plist where you can specify custom viewController like this:

```
 <dict>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Manage multiple reminders</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>IASKViewControllerClass</key>
            <string>RemindersViewController</string>
            <key>IASKViewControllerSelector</key>
            <string>init</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Reminders list</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
```

P.S. This is just code snap from plist file with title